# Django model form and visible_fields

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use Django's ModelForm, but limit the number of fields I show by using the fields attribute. Here are the relevant parts of my code.

### django and python version

```
python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> print (django.VERSION)
(1, 7, 0, 'final', 0)
>>>
```

### models.py:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
....
```

### forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'password']
```

### template

```
  {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag}} {{ field}}
  {% endfor %}
```

I am seeing a couple of issues.

1) when I visit the page, the template is showing the created_at field as well, although Meta.fields does not have that column.

2) The first time I import the form class in the shell, I see a deprecation warning, even though I have the fields attribute in the Meta class

```
>>> from account.forms import RegisterForm
/home/django/django_project/account/forms.py:4: RemovedInDjango18Warning: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is deprecated - form RegisterForm needs updating
  class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
```

Any pointers?

Comment: which django version are you using?

Comment: python 2.7, Django 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Set the `exclude` attribute of the ModelForm’s inner `Meta class` to a list of fields to be excluded from the form.

In your case, it would be like this.

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=User
        exclude = ['created_at']
```

Note that in Django 1.7+ it is now required to specify the fields that are to be excluded, via `exclude`.